# Formula development assistance

Tags: excel

Good Morning,

Can you help to develop a formula to do the below task please:

The formula will be in Cell J8, i need the formula to look into Cell I8, if the formula finds a date entered then it returns YES in Cell J8, if it finds the symbol - then it returns the - symbol and if it is blank then it returns nothing.

Im a complete novice when it comes to formulas and i know only basics, this is what me and my cohort came up with but it doesnt work as intended

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I8),"",IF(ISNUMBER(I8),"YES","-"))
```

If this can be developed further to complete the task required we would be greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(I8),"",IF(I8="-","-",IF(ISNUMBER(I8),"Yes","None")))
```

isnumber is not the ultimate solution for detecting date. use vba

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=IF(ISBLANK(I8),"",IF(I8="-",I8, IF(ISERROR(DATE(YEAR(I8),MONTH(I8),DAY(I8))),"","Yes")))`

There formula check if there is a date and if that date is valid. If there is anything else in there cell except `-`, `Empty String` or `Valid Date` you will get nothing for result.